# Tab auto completion doesn't work with apt-get install (kubuntu)

Tags: shell, autocomplete, kubuntu

I've noticed a strange behavior of my shell on Kubuntu. Auto completion doesn't work well when I try to install new software. It works only for default commands (when I type "apt-get inst" and I press tab, "install" is autocompleted) but doesn't work when I type a portion of name of software I want to install. 
I've tried to uncomment `/etc/bash.bashrc` lines for auto completion, but nothing changed. What's wrong?

Comment: Have you run `apt-get update` at least once?

Comment: Did you try hitting tab a few times?  I think it takes about 3 if there are a lot of possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, assure your `sudo apt-get update` works well and all your sources are ok.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/136535/54949) they solve by installing `auto-complete-el`

```
sudo apt-get install auto-complete-el
```

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/203013/54949) they solved because accidentally `~/.bashrc` was deleted. You can get a working copy from `/etc/skel/.bashrc`

Answer (score 4):

You need to have the package `bash-completion` installed. The default `.bashrc` for user accounts will source the provided files. If it is not, you will need the following in your `.bashrc`:

```
. /etc/bash_completion
```

Comment: i've already that package installed

Comment: SOLVED: i've remove and clean old bash-completion and install it again. Now seems it works

Comment: Ok, today i've reboot my system and auto completion doesn't work again... i've solved by install auto-complete-el